# Adding a second title to a Custom Post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

At the moment I am just learning about Custom Post Types so I am unsure how to proceed from here.

I created a custom post for events, it is almost identical to a normal post with just slightly different wording. But the reason I made one is because I want to add a second title after the initial title.

To make this as easy as possible for the user I would ideally like this text field just underneath the first one above the main editor. Just wondering how do I add that here?

```
register_post_type('events',
    array(  
        'label' => 'Events',
        'description' => 'Events section',
        'public' => true,'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
        'query_var' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),
        'taxonomies' => array('category',),
        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'Events',
            'singular_name' => 'Event',
            'menu_name' => 'Events',
            'add_new' => 'Add Event',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Event',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Event',
            'new_item' => 'New Event',
            'view' => 'View Event',
            'view_item' => 'View Event',
            'search_items' => 'Search Events',
            'not_found' => 'No Events Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Events Found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Event',
        ),
    ) 
);
```

**`'title'`** seems to be the standard one, so I'm wondering if I can create another instance of that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update: there's [an easy way to do it using some hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950010/how-to-go-about-modifying-the-wordpress-pages-add-new-screen/23036236#23036236) and managing the `save_post` just like a regular meta box.*

---

No, there can only be one title.

You have to create a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to record the value of a *Second Title*.

And, problem is that it cannot be put between the title and the content box.

I suggest the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It's been actively developed and is quite handy for generating a variety of CF's.

---

This is how I'd do it, click on the images to enlarge:

### Configure one Advanced Custom Field

> [image: acf configuration]

---

### Result in Custom Post Type screen

> [image]

---

### Moving the field with jQuery help

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'so_13726274_move_field' );

function so_13726274_move_field()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {     
            $('#acf-text').prependTo('#postdivrich');
            $('#acf-field_50baa73272855').css('width','100%');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

#### Results in

> [image]

#### jQuery Notes

- `$('#acf-text')` is the *container div*, corresponds to "#acf-FIELD_NAME"
- `$('#acf-field_50baa73272855')` is the *text field* itself, we need this command because the width gets shorter when we move the *container div*
- the text field #ID has to be detected in your own installation as it won't be the same, use Chrome Inspector or FireBug

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by changing your editor layout for your custom post type. This site will show you how you can do that. You can make a box inside your editor for a Subhead line.

http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/